# Retrieving data from MATLAB GUI and sending it to Excel

Tags: matlab, user-interface, export-to-excel, figure, brush

The GUI I've created uses subplots and displays 5 plots within the GUI. The plots only display if certain parameters are chosen and they are calculated using the given parameters. I saw that people use `saveas` to save the plots as a figure, which I would like to use, however when I include it in the code I don't get any error messages nor do i get a saved `.fig` file.

Ideally I would like to have a function similar to `databrush` in my GUI so I can select the data that I want and save it into an Excel.

The reason I want to do this is because I have two programs. One program calculates responses with data, whereas the other calculates responses based on a line of best fit or polynomial fit from the same data. I would like to put both output data from the same input into an Excel file and graph and compare their differences.

How can I do this?

Comment: It is strange that nothing happens while you don't get an error message. Could you run the code with `dbstop if warning`, and if that does not help can you try to let it save something else to the same location?

Comment: Well, i've tried again however this time it saives the figure.. but of the entire GUI instead of just the sub plots.